# Как в Oracle Database настроить ежедневные backup-ы?

Tags: oracle, резервное-копирование, база-данных

Как в Oracle Database настроить ежедневные backup-ы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cron + rman.

1. `man cron`
2. [RMAN User's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmquick.htm#BABJAGIB)
3. [RMAN в примерах] (здесь была мёртвая ссылка)